# Can I use relative URL to access a page immediately below the current directory?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I'm using ASP.NET routing in a web forms application.

Let's say I have a route `produce/fruit` to a page about fruit.

Lets also say that I have a route `produce/fruit/apples` to a page about apples.

So, `produce/fruit` is a page and a directory.  Can I create a hyperlink from this page to `produce/fruit/apples` with a relative URL, that doesn't have to include the current page?

If I use the anchor below from the page at `produce/fruit` it will take me to `produce/apples`, which does not exist. However, if I use the same link on the same page at `produce/fruit/` it will take me to the correct page/sub-directory.

```
<a href="apples">apples</a>
```

Of course, my link from `produce/fruit`could be `<a href="fruit/apples">apples</a>` but then I need to include the current page name, and it wouldn't work from `produce/fruit/`.

I feel like there is some really simple html that I've forgotten.

Comment: did you try `<a href="apples/">apples</a>` ?

Comment: Did you try `<a href="/apples">apples</a>` - Btw `produce/fruit` is not a page AND a directory. `produce/fruit` is a page & `produce/fruit/` is a directory

Comment: That goes to `produce/apples/` as a directory, but doesn't keep the current directory in the path.

Comment: `<a href="/apples">apples</a>` goes to `/apples` i.e. just a non-existent page at the root.  

I think you've identified why this is as much a question about routing as it is is about basic html.  I think that would work if routing wasn't involved.

Comment: If root then try `<a href="./apples">apples</a>`. The `./` means current directory

Comment: Yeah, that's the same as `<a href="apples">apples</a>`.  It goes to the non-existent `produce/apples`.

It perceives, rightly, that the current directory is `/produce/`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that you're not accounting for a slash (or lack thereof) at the end of the current URL.

For example, if the URL is `/produce/fruit` and you have an href like `apples` then the resulting link will be `/produce/apples`. However, if the URL is `produce/fruit/` with the same href, then the resulting link will be `/product/fruit/apples`. In short, you just need to ensure that you always use trailing slashes in your URLs. To aid in this, you can enable `routes.AppendTrailingSlash` in your RouteConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
```

Comment: We might have to do just that, but we'd have to update all the static links in the site content. 

I was hoping for a way of dealing with it on a link by link, or even route by route basis.

Comment: There's no foolproof way to have a relative href if you can't guarantee a trailing slash in the URL. FWIW, though, you don't necessarily need to update all the static links. The way this flag works is that MVC will rewrite the URL to include the slash at the end. In other words, if you click a link to just `/produce/fruit`, the URL in the address bar will be `/produce/fruit/` (with the slash).